# Send E-Mail from Powershell Script to Multiple Recipients based on ActiveDirectory User

Tags: script, powershell

I have a script that I would like to dynamically send an email containing some info and go to certain people based on who in the company is running the script thanks to ActiveDirectory.

I have another portion of code that detects which OU the user or service account is running this from so for the sake of this question don't worry about that.

What I have so far is something like this:

```
function SendEmail 
{ 
Send-MailMessage -To $Recipients -From "Info <noreply@domain.com>" -Subject "Account Report" -Body $Body -SmtpServer smtpserver.domain.com
}

 $To = Get-ADUser -Filter "(Name -like '*')" -Properties Name, EmailAddress -Searchbase $OUDetected | Format-List EmailAddress | Out-String
```

I am trying to utilize the Send-MailMessage cmdlet but emails have to be sent in a particular format to recipients.

A single recipient is:

> `"John Doe <doe.john@domain.com>"`

Multiple recipients should look like:

> `"John Doe`<`doe.john@domain.com>", "Jane Doe <doe.jane@domain.com>"`

The issue is tricky then as the result of $To is in the format:

> EmailAddress: doe.john@domain.com
>
> EmailAddress: doe.jane@domain.com

This format needs to be converted to the multiple recipient example as shown above.

I am at a loss at how to properly grab the data, format it and be sure it stays in the format that Send-Mailmessage can use.

**TL;DR - There needs to be a way that grabs the email address(es) of each user(s) in a given OU in ActiveDirectory and format that/those email address(es) so it may send using Send-MailMessage**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Send E-Mail from Powershell Script to Multiple Recipients based on ActiveDirectory User**
>
> This format needs to be converted to the multiple recipient example as
>   shown above.
>
> I am at a loss at how to properly grab the data, format it and be sure
>   it stays in the format that Send-Mailmessage can use.
>
> **There needs to be a way that grabs the email address(es) of each user(s) in a given OU in ActiveDirectory and format that/those email
>   address(es) so it may send using Send-MailMessage**

Below is the PowerShell logic to get the output in the comma separated values excluding NULL values for the email address properties of those accounts your logic grabs.

I tested and confirmed this format works as expected in my environment without using the logic you state to not worry about (e.g. `$OUDetected`).

- Please note the format `Send-MailMessage` with the `-To` parameter works just fine with a format of `doe.john@domain.com,doe.jane@domain.com` so each email address with only the local mailbox part and the domain name separated by commas is sufficient.

I'll put **My Working Example** below and I'll put the **Your Example** below based on what you gave and how I was able to confirm it worked fine in my case.

### Your Example (with my working logic added)

```
function SendEmail 
{ 
Send-MailMessage -To $Recipients -From "Info <noreply@domain.com>" -Subject "Account Report" -Body $Body -SmtpServer smtpserver.domain.com
}

 $To = (Get-ADUser -Filter "(Name -like '*')" -Properties Name, EmailAddress -Searchbase $OUDetected | Where-Object {$_.EmailAddress -ne $null} | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddress) -join "," | Out-String
```

### Your Example (Iterated To Addresses)

```
function SendEmail 
{
Send-MailMessage -To $To -From "Info <noreply@domain.com>" -Subject "Account Report" -Body $Body -SmtpServer smtpserver.domain.com
}

$ToAddresses = Get-ADUser -Filter "(Name -like '*')" -Properties Name, EmailAddress -Searchbase $OUDetected | 
Where-Object {$_.EmailAddress -ne $null} | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddress

ForEach ($ToAddress in $ToAddresses) {
   $To = $ToAddress
   SendEmail
}
```

### My Working Example

```
(Get-ADUser -Filter "(Name -like '*')" -Properties Name, EmailAddress | Where-Object {$_.EmailAddress -ne $null} | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddress) -join "," | Out-String
```

Comment: This iteration did it! I was able to send it to multiple recipients. Unfortunately they send as individual emails but this is much better than not sending at all. Thank you for your repeated assistance! Edit: Actually changing `$ToAddress` to `$To` and not using the `foreach` loop did let me send to all recipients. Thanks again!